# Error when trying to import excel data to SQL Server 2008

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an excel file that has data. The first row has the columns.  I am trying throw SSIS to import these data on a database. On the edit mappings I am setting  the destination columns “Nvarchar (max) “ .  All the columns are imported successfully on Sql server but one column produce the bellow error. I have try to edit the “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel”  registry key from 8 to 64 but I still taking the same error. I have follow also the instructions from this post [Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page When importing from Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629024/text-was-truncated-or-one-or-more-characters-had-no-match-in-the-target-code-pag) 
 with no luck.
The error that I am taking:

"Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with output column "MyColumn,M" (63) on output "Excel Source Output" (9). The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "MyColumn,M" (63)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "MyColumn,M" (63)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Page1$" (1) returned error code 0xC020902A.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 "

Comment: What's the actual length for the column of the data row that is throwing the error?  What is the data in the first 64 rows that would give a hint to excel that the data type is something smaller?

Comment: Try setting that registry key to an even higher number.  63 isn't the row number that the error occurs on, it's the ID of the object in the SSIS package the wizard is creating behind the scenes.

Comment: Is it make sense if i give 128 value or should i put much bigger?