# SSIS: [Excel Source [65]] Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

When I am trying to load data from Excel sheet having 23K rows into SQL Table, I am getting Error

> [Excel Source [65]] Error: There was an error with Excel
>   Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Proc Description] on Excel
>   Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was:
>   "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
>   target code page.".
>
> [Excel Source [65]] Error: The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source
>   Output].Columns[Proc Description]" failed because truncation occurred,
>   and the truncation row disposition on "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel
>   Source Output].Columns[Proc Description]" specifies failure on
>   truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the
>   specified component.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC020902A. 
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

I am able to fetch only 4k rows only. I did make sure that Data Types and Data Length matches in Source and Destination. Please help me

Comment: Set destination table column to `NVARCHAR` with proper length

Comment: Hi the column in the Excel Source is NVARCHAR(MAX) and in the Destination Table also NVARCHAR(MAX), but still problem exists

Comment: The excel driver tends to truncate strings at times, by guessing lengths based on first few rows in the file - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629024/text-was-truncated-or-one-or-more-characters-had-no-match-in-the-target-code-pag

Comment: Set the SSIS datatype of the source component columns to the correct length (in advanced properties of source component).