# Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

I want to import .xlsx file data in MS SQL SERVER 2008. So, using SQL Server import and export wizard I start to import by selecting .xlsx file. Here I got the error "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page".

I tried google it and I got 2-3 solution and I start trying those one by one.

1. I tried change data type size to nvarchar(max) --- not work
2. I tried by adding more then 255 character in particular column and give size nvarchar(max) --- not work
3. I tried save .xlsx file to .csv and start importing by selecting data source flat file --- not work
4. I also tried selecting DT_NTEXT --- not work

Please explain me how do I complete this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us an example of problematic data? One record should be enough. The definition of table into which you want to import data will be also useful.

Comment: Did you read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629024/text-was-truncated-or-one-or-more-characters-had-no-match-in-the-target-code-pag?rq=1

Comment: There are 78 fields and in "Manufacturer " and  "Manufacturer address" field I got this problem

Comment: You can also try bulk insert or openrowset

Comment: I have used SSIS and it works thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use the SSIS for this task and its work. The fields with error are move to the flat file and other all fields are successfully moved to the database as I need.

I get the help from following link:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/